# Activate prepareforsegue with qr code

Tags: ios, swift, segue, qr-code

I have the following code and what it is supposed to do, is this:
When the camera detects a QR code, it should open up my DetailViewController, through the identifier: SendDataSegue. The problem is, when the QR code is detected nothing really happens? Can anyone help me here? It is at the bottom of the code that I am trying to use the prepareforsegue.

```js
func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [AnyObject]!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
        
        // Check if the metadataObjects array is not nil and it contains at least one object.
        if metadataObjects == nil || metadataObjects.count == 0 {
            qrCodeFrameView?.frame = CGRectZero
            messageLabel.text = "No barcode/QR code is detected"
            return
        }
        
        // Get the metadata object.
        let metadataObj = metadataObjects[0] as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject
        
        // Here we use filter method to check if the type of metadataObj is supported
        // Instead of hardcoding the AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode, we check if the type
        // can be found in the array of supported bar codes.
        if supportedBarCodes.contains(metadataObj.type) {
//        if metadataObj.type == AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode {
            // If the found metadata is equal to the QR code metadata then update the status label's text and set the bounds
            let barCodeObject = videoPreviewLayer?.transformedMetadataObjectForMetadataObject(metadataObj)
            qrCodeFrameView?.frame = barCodeObject!.bounds
            
            if metadataObj.stringValue != nil {
                
                
                func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
                    if (segue.identifier == "SendDataSegue") {
                        // pass data to next view
                    }
                }
                
                
                
                
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You don't declare that method there. You just do `self.performSegue("SendDataSegue", sender:nil)`.

Comment: But what if I have a label, on my DetailViewController that should be changed to what the QR code says?

Comment: When using your code @Larme it says: Value of  type ViewController has no member preformSegue

Comment: I don't think that your code even compile. The issue is that you are writing this: `func methodOne(parameters1...){codeStuff1; func methodTwo(parameters2...){codeStuff2}}` instead of  `func methodOne(parameters1...){codeStuff1;} func methodTwo(parameters2...){codeStuff2}`

Comment: @Larme the code is working. If I remove the prepareforsegue and add a little code of changing the label in the viewcontroller, then it is doing that. I just can't get it to go to another viewcontroller?

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code helped me:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SendDataSegue", sender:self)


            }
```

Does anyone know how to pass data through that? I can pass data through a normal func prepareforsegue, but how do I do it through this?